# Build app so it can run on different versions of OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, build

I have an app that needs to be run on MAC OS X 10.5,10.6,10.7

I'm using XCode 4.02 and iOS SDK 4.3. My build settings are 10.6 MAC OS X, and Deployment target is 10.5.

Is this the right way to do it, or I should use the Mac OS X 10.5 SDK? I can't find it, I have only 10.6.

Right now my application runs on 10.5, but not properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are a serious apple developer, you should upgrade to Lion. You should also be using the latest SDK, OSX 10.7 that comes bundled with the latest version of XCode 4.2.X (It's free from the MAC APP Store). If you need to have your app run on previous versions of OSX, the correct way to do this is to set the "Deployment Target" (found in the build settings) to 10.5.

XCode/SDK updates are just like any other software update, they contain bug fixes and more importantly security patches, so you should ALWAYS be using the latest versions.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm using Deployment Target as you said. But having some problem on 10.5 when I launch it.

Comment: If you are using any third party frameworks, you do need to make sure that they were compiled with a deployment target of <10.5 as well.